# How do I generate a list of checkboxes?

Tags: vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display an unknown number of checkboxes on the page in the form of:

```
<input type="checkbox"... />
<label for...>
```

My database table has the information about these checkboxes

```
Id
Name
```

For simplicity let's say that `Id` is just an integer and `Name` is a colour ("Red", "Green").

**How best can I generate these boxes?**

My current code is

`Model`

```
Public Property Colours As IEnumerable(Of CheckBox)

Public Sub New()
    Colours = ...
End Sub
```

`View`

```
@For Each item In Model.Colours
    @Html.CheckBox(item.Text, item.Checked)
    @Html.Label(item.Text, item.Text)
Next
```

**Also, how are CheckBoxList and CheckBoxField supposed to be used?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using an extension to generate the check box list, rather than rolling it manually, such as:

- [CheckBoxListFor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/CheckBoxList-For-A-missing-MVC-extension#Introduction)
- [Fabrik.commons](https://github.com/benfoster/Fabrik.Common)
- [MVC Controls Toolkit](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Some colleagues had a problem with previous versions of the MVC Controls Toolkit. That's just hearsay on my part as I was working on something different at the time but just thought I'd mention it in case YMMV.

Re: "how are CheckBoxList and CheckBoxField" supposed to be used, the way I look at it is:

- CheckBoxList for a set of related options and you want people to select none, one or possibly more than one
- CheckBoxField for when you have a single option which is yes/no or true/false in nature (e.g. a "tick me to unsubscribe" box)

HTH,
Nathan

Comment: What's the difference between CheckBoxField and CheckBox?

Comment: Hi Rowan, do you mean between [System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxfield.aspx) and Html.CheckBox (like what you were using in your original post)? If so, then CheckBoxField is meant to be used with ASP.NET web forms so it has the extra things that web forms needs (as you could describe that as a stateful system whereas the web is "stateless") whereas Html.CheckBox just gives you an <input> tag as a checkbox

Comment: ...so I guess from a practical perspective it just depends on the type of app you work on with CheckBoxField being for an ASP.NET Web Forms app. That is my (simplistic) understanding - someone else can probably give you a better explanation :-)